# Visual way to see dependencies/connections between methods in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, methods, bluej, connection

Is there a way in Android Studio (or in other tools) to see the dependencies/connections between all methods within a project, similar to how BlueJ shows connections between classes (but at a method level)?  For example, to show that method `doSomething` is called by `getInput` and `calcResults`, and that `doSomething` calls `resizeObject` and `findBoundary`.